# How to resolve Gekko Level Regulation example error?

Tags: gekko

I copied the Level Regulation with MPC example directly as shown at this link:
http://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/LevelControl

I am getting two errors, and one is stopping the simulation from completing each time I run a simulation:

- Despite the example appearing to have a consistent time step, the following error flags an inconsistent time increment using the same code as the example.
- Also getting a duplicate variable error that occurs after many iterations.

What should be corrected with the example to resolve this error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Changing the m.time line to the following seems to have resolved the one error on time sequence: m.time = np.arange(10).tolist()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public server runs the application in a folder that is based on a unique user ID that is determined at run-time. The [MPC script](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/LevelControl?action=sourceblock&num=1) doesn't return an error with Python 3.11 on Windows. One thing to try is to set `remote=False` to solve locally and not on the public server.

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
```

If the public server is used, make sure there aren't two clients accessing the public server at the same time. This could put duplicate files on the server that would cause this error. Switching to the local option is likely the most reliable.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import csv
from gekko import GEKKO

# create MPC with GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = [0,1,2,4,8,12,16,20]

# empirical constants
Kp_h1 = 1.3
tau_h1 = 18.4
Kp_h2 = 1
tau_h2 = 24.4

# manipulated variable
p = m.MV(value=0,lb=1e-5,ub=1)
p.STATUS = 1
p.DCOST = 0.01
p.FSTATUS = 0

# unmeasured state
h1 = m.Var(value=0.0)

# controlled variable
h2 = m.CV(value=0.0)
h2.STATUS = 1
h2.FSTATUS = 1
h2.TAU = 20
h2.TR_INIT = 1

# equations
m.Equation(tau_h1*h1.dt()==-h1 + Kp_h1*p)
m.Equation(tau_h2*h2.dt()==-h2 + Kp_h2*h1)

# options
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2

# simulated system (for measurements)
def tank(levels,t,pump,valve):
    h1 = max(1.0e-10,levels[0])
    h2 = max(1.0e-10,levels[1])
    c1 = 0.08 # inlet valve coefficient
    c2 = 0.04 # tank outlet coefficient
    dhdt1 = c1 * (1.0-valve) * pump - c2 * np.sqrt(h1)
    dhdt2 = c1 * valve * pump + c2 * np.sqrt(h1) - c2 * np.sqrt(h2)
    if h1>=1.0 and dhdt1>0.0:
        dhdt1 = 0
    if h2>=1.0 and dhdt2>0.0:
        dhdt2 = 0
    dhdt = [dhdt1,dhdt2]
    return dhdt

# Initial conditions (levels)
h0 = [0,0]

# Time points to report the solution
tf = 400
t = np.linspace(0,tf,tf+1)

# Set point
sp = np.zeros(tf+1)
sp[5:100] = 0.5
sp[100:200] = 0.8
sp[200:300] = 0.2
sp[300:] = 0.5

# Inputs that can be adjusted
pump = np.zeros(tf+1)

# Disturbance
valve = 0.0

# Record the solution
y = np.zeros((tf+1,2))
y[0,:] = h0

# Create plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.ion()
plt.show()

# Simulate the tank step test
for i in range(1,tf):
    #########################
    # MPC ###################
    #########################
    # measured height
    h2.MEAS = y[i,1]
    # set point deadband
    h2.SPHI = sp[i]+0.01
    h2.SPLO = sp[i]-0.01
    h2.SP = sp[i]
    # solve MPC
    m.solve(disp=False)
    # retrieve 1st pump new value
    pump[i] = p.NEWVAL

    #########################
    # System ################
    #########################
    # Specify the pump and valve
    inputs = (pump[i],valve)
    # Integrate the model
    h = odeint(tank,h0,[0,1],inputs)
    # Record the result
    y[i+1,:] = h[-1,:]
    # Reset the initial condition
    h0 = h[-1,:]

    # update plot every 5 cycles
    if (i%5==3):
        plt.clf()
        plt.subplot(2,1,1)
        plt.plot(t[0:i],sp[0:i],'k-')    
        plt.plot(t[0:i],y[0:i,0],'b-')
        plt.plot(t[0:i],y[0:i,1],'r--')
        plt.ylabel('Height (m)')
        plt.legend(['Set point','Height 1','Height 2'])
        plt.subplot(2,1,2)
        plt.plot(t[0:i],pump[0:i],'k-')
        plt.ylabel('Pump')    
        plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.01)

# Construct and save data file
data = np.vstack((t,pump))
data = np.hstack((np.transpose(data),y))
np.savetxt('data.txt',data,delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thank you John. Setting remote=False solved the problem. I was only running one problem at a time.